# Is header propagation only java-agent can do?

Tags: istio, envoyproxy, javaagents, servicemesh

I have three services A, B, C, and the calling relationship between them is A->B->C.

I would like to pass in a special http header when calling A, and subsequent requests caused by this request will automatically carry this http header.

Is it the fact that only `java-agent` can do it without hacking into the service code? Envoy seems to require users to modify the service code to explicitly configure the http headers.

Environment:

- K8s-1.20.6 on TencentCloud
- Istio-1.12.1 (installed using `demo` profile)

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes and Istio did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem. What exactly did you try?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak Sorry for not providing environmental information, it has been added.

Answer (score 1):

> Is header propagation only java-agent can do?

No, there are couple of ways to achive [header propagation in istio](https://istio.io/latest/about/faq/distributed-tracing/#how-to-support-tracing), based on you specific situation.

> Header propagation may be accomplished through client libraries, such as [Zipkin](https://zipkin.io/pages/tracers_instrumentation.html) or [Jaeger](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-client-java/tree/master/jaeger-core#b3-propagation). It may also be accomplished manually, as documented in the [Distributed Tracing Task](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/overview/#trace-context-propagation).

Look also at the topic [What is the best practice of HTTP header propagation?](https://discuss.istio.io/t/what-is-the-best-practice-of-http-header-propagation/1974)

As you can see, there is no one perfect way to help you achieve your goal. See also:

[Using OpenTracing with Istio/Envoy](https://medium.com/jaegertracing/using-opentracing-with-istio-envoy-d8a4246bdc15)
[Headers propagation with hpropagate](https://medium.com/ww-engineering/headers-propagation-with-hpropagate-27de8347f76a)

Comment: From [header propagation in istio](https://istio.io/latest/about/faq/distributed-tracing/#how-to-support-tracing), it seems that the application still needs to be modified to pass the header down while I want to know if Istio can do this kind of automatic delivery without modifying application...

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that the only available methods have already been described in my answer.